# IIS experiences super slow requests intermittently

Tags: performance, iis

I have been trying to pinpoint an error in a legacy application for our customers. They have complained about slow response times and checking IIS logs I can see that sometimes requests that shouldn't take over 500 ms take 10-30 seconds.

There seems to be no pattern: these requests happen with requests handled by our application, they happen with small static files (pictures and .js-files), they happen during high and low traffic. There doesn't seem to be a request type happening before or during these requests that would cause this to happen.

I have tried failed request tracing for long requests but everything happening in IIS pipeline seems to take 0 ms or at least close to that. Could this be caused by extremely slow network connections or our legacy application blocking threads (or something completely different)?

Comment: is the application .net based? if that is the case you should turn on logging for when the application pool is recycled to see if that happens at the same time.

Comment: It is not .net based. Unfortunately it uses a custom ISAPI module. But I turned on recycle logging just in case, good idea.

Comment: Legacy ... so your running in a VM? on a new OS, which takes security more serious and makes a security lookup on the addresses your ask to download?

Comment: You can only profiling the worker process to learn more or use hang dump analysis. If neither is what you know how to proceed, ask the ISAPI vendor or developers to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my own issue.

The slowness experienced by our customer is likely caused by other factors. Compared request statistics to other services (with completely different technology) and found that they all have similar slow requests now and then probably caused by slow connections.

Useful tools:

- [Failed request logging for long requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)
- [Performance monitor and server performance logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722148(v=ws.11).aspx)
- [Logging application pool recycle events in log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753412(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Log parser studio for querying and analyzing IIS logs](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765)