# Why is my website experiencing random slow api requests?

Tags: asp.net, performance, api, networking, iis-8.5

I have a VB.NET/Vue website hosted on an internal IIS 8.5 Windows 2012R2 Server. Our company has about 30 users using the site at any given time. The users are experiencing random delays throughout the day and on some days there's no delays (site works great most of the time). What I'm looking for is any suggestions on where to start looking to solve the issue. Here's what I've found so far.

1. User goes to site and initiates an api request from the UI
2. User sees a loading icon for anywhere up to a minute or so while the request returns
3. The request eventually reaches the server after some time and executes really fast within milliseconds and returns the response to the user
4. By this time, many users have already refreshed the page making new requests that succeed on page load. For the users that are patient and wait for the response, it eventually returns the response.

Here's some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

So to sum everything up, there are several users experiencing delays on a daily basis.

Some days we don’t have any delays, but most days we have several users experiencing multiple delays of several seconds to 30 seconds to 1 minute.

I’ve found all this using LogRocket and NewRelic and what is happening is all these requests are completing within milliseconds, but the request doesn’t seem to reach the server for some period of time.

I’ve been monitoring the CPU/Memory/Network on these servers and it all seems fine to me during when these issues occur.

It seems that the problem lies between the users computer and whatever hardware/software exists before reaching the web server.

Update here... Found that the problem is occurring on the users computer in all these instances. Using google chrome's performance api, I was able to track timing info for these requests and found that the problem is in the fetchStart. So whatever is happening here is the cause of the issue.

Example below:

entryType: resource
startTime: 1119531.820000033
duration: 56882.43999995757
initiatorType: xmlhttprequest
nextHopProtocol: http/1.1
workerStart: 0
redirectStart: 0
redirectEnd: 0
fetchStart: 1119531.820000033
domainLookupStart: 1176401.0199999902
domainLookupEnd: 1176402.2699999623
connectStart: 1176402.2699999623
connectEnd: 1176404.8350000521
secureConnectionStart: 1176403.6700000288
requestStart: 1176404.8549999716
responseStart: 1176413.5300000198
responseEnd: 1176414.2599999905
transferSize: 15145
encodedBodySize: 14884
decodedBodySize: 14884
serverTiming: []
workerTiming: []

fetchStart is at 1119531.820000033, then requestStart is at 1176404.8549999716 so the problem is something between fetchStart and requestStart. Still looking into what is causing this.

Comment: Without knowing what functions are being called by the "random slow requests" we would have no idea how to determine why the request is slow.  We would need significantly more information.  Please revise your question to use more than one paragraph, and to clarify what's being done within the requests, whether the requests are similar or not, whether there are specifica requests that seem to be more troublesome than others, and so on.

Comment: What are the tools in "with my monitoring tools"? "I'm able to see the time", and then what is "the time"? The entire request/response round time, or just a portion of it? You have to carefully analyze the slowness pattern and then figure out what might be wrong, as "random slow requests" without any pattern is impossible to resolve.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the response. I thought I might get a replay asking for more info because this problem is infinitely hard to solve. I didn't want to write a whole book on here but am really just looking for a few ideas on what to check and where to look. I'll try and revise the question. To answer your question, there doesn't seem to be any particular troublesome requests. They all execute fast on the server once it gets there. Just happens randomly through the day. These same requests usually work fine all day. Just a few times a day they seem to take long to get to the server it seems.

Comment: @LexLi I agree... "random slow requests" without any pattern is impossible to resolve which is why I've come here. I'll try to update the question more clearly with the one pattern I've found in all of this. The tool I use for front end logging is LogRocket. That's where I can view the users having the slow loading issues and the time the request was sent from the user's computer as well as the time the response came back. On the backend I use NewRelic and IIS Logs to view the time the request reached the server.

Comment: Perahps sql server table locks are occuring? I would check the sql profiler and monitor - it may well not be load or memory (does not seem to be the case). But, sql table locks could be a issue. If there is sorts and pulls on tables - look for a large table with a sort, but no index. And the other possible? you use session() a lot, and ALSO are using sql server based sessions(). What can occur is session() locks if  you say use Server.Transfer(url) in place of Response.Request(url).

Comment: my psychic debugging hat says: it's possible it's locks in the DB, or a garbage collection occurring; are you disposing of connections?  Is your App. pool recycling? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131887/iis-experiences-super-slow-requests-intermittently

Comment: You can use FRT to see which module is taking longer, for infromation about FRT, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Thank for the replies. The app pool isn't recycling during business hours from the logs I see in the event viewer. App recycles at 12AM the log says and users are only on the site around 7AM-5PM PST. Don't suspect the DB since the transaction runs within milliseconds so it's something before the request hits the code. I dispose of connections with the "using" syntax also so it's not that. Not sure if garbage collection is occurring somewhere but doesn't seem likely. Looked into FRT but haven't set it up yet so I can do that. Thinking it can be network related possibly too? Any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure where the problem occurred, you can use FRT to see which module takes a long time and then analyze it.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, we are experiencing something very similar with a small fraction of our customers. There is a significant gap between the timing api `requestStart` and the `startTime`. This gap can be up to *8* minutes -- I admire the patience of customers waiting that long. The wait periods are also close to multiples of a minute.

In our case, it appears that there is a (transparent?) proxy between those browsers and our server infrastructure which appears to be triggering the problem. In particular, it forces a downgrade of HTTP/2 to HTTP/1.1. Whitelisting our website in that proxy does solve the problem. This isn't a very satisfactory solution, but it does make the customer happier!

[UPDATE]

In our case, it turned out that we were sending a Content-Length header with a non-zero value on a 304 response. This is technically invalid and it caused problems with the proxy. This happened because of the Django `CommonMiddleware` which always puts a content-length header on responses. The solution was to add a new piece of middleware that strips out the `content-length` (and content) on a 304 response.

It turned out that the content was already being stripped by our nginx frontend, but it is better not to generate it in the first place.

And what was the content? -- in our case, it was the 4 characters 'null'!